# Is there any property of the matrix consists of the normalized eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is diagonalizable, then one can find the eigenvalue decomposition:
$$ X = T \Lambda T^{-1},$$ 
where each column of $T$ can be viewed as normalized eigenvectors of $X$.

**Question**

Is there any property on $T$? Say singular value of $T$? I know if $X$ is symmetric, then we have everything desired... But in general, since $T$ is normalized, is there any nice property?

Comment: Even if $X$ is symmetric, we don't have "everything desired" unless we pick *the right $T$*.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you cannot say anything better about $T$ than its being invertible and its columns (or rows? not having time to think right now) being normalized. After all, you can conjugate $\operatorname{diag}\left(1,2,\ldots,n\right)$ by any invertible matrix and call the result $X$; then $T$ will be the invertible matrix you have conjugated by up to scaling of columns (or rows?).

Comment: It is not clear why you write 'each column of T can be viewed as normalized eigenvectors of X.'.